# Slick slider прижимает картинки вправо

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемкой. Воткнул слик-слайдер  на карточку в интернет магазине (блок рекомендуемое для каждого отдельного товара в магазине). Изначально в параметрах выведено 4 слайда для показа, но на некоторых карточках могут быть больше 4х слайдов(соответственно появляется прокрутка), а на других может быть и 1.

Проблема в том, что когда выводится меньше 4х слайдов, то они почему-то прижимаются вправо =)) В инструкции к слайдеру что-то не нашёл инфы.

Братва, выручайте !!! =)) Как сделать отправную точку от левого края?

[image: Один слайд прижат влево]

Comment: А код предоставить не хотите? Какая разметка? Какие стили?

Comment: Сори, думал может у кого просто было подобное=)

Думаю так будет проще:
http://passo.web-ritm.ru/slick.html

Стили - style.css
Скрипты - js.js

Соответственно в скриптах обрабатывается .recomended-rotator